# coldfusion decrypt in php

Tags: php, coldfusion, encryption

I'm not English speaker, sorry in advance.

I have a ColdFusion 6.1 application, and now I'm trying to migrate to another environment. In the ColdFusion application, the passwords of my users are crypted with a ColdFusion function:

`password_encrypted=toBase64(encrypt(text,key));`

Does anyone know how can I decrypt it in PHP? I don't know what the cypher algorithm used in CFMX 6.1 is. I think that the name of the algorithm is `CFMX_COMPAT`, but I don't know if it has an equivalent in PHP.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the default CFMX_COMPAT function is simply a XOR.

So in PHP this would be as simple as:

```
$password_encrypted = base64_encode($text ^ $key);
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

I was curious so I wrote a little script to test, and this might be reversed, here is the encrypt/decrypt.

```
<?php

$text = 'test';
$key = 'asdf';

$password_encrypted = base64_encode($key ^ $text);

echo $password_encrypted . "<br>\n";

$password_decrypted = base64_decode($password_encrypted) ^ $key;

echo $password_decrypted;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Evolve. Your answer is probably correct, but it not works in my problem. I can't do it, but thank you very much. I will try decrypt all the passwords with ColdFusion and store them in my DB.

Comment: This isn't the same as coldfusion's CFMX_COMPAT encryption algorithm, I'm not sure which algorithm you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a dumb question, why not try `UN-encrypting` using Coldfusion 6? Insert that into the record as plain text (while in DEV).

Then encrypt with any format you want using PHP. That way you are 100% sure it will be decrypted/understood from Coldfusion to PHP.

As reference here is the CF 6 encrypt() fn:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6/CFML_Reference/functions-pt175.htm

and here is decrypt() fn:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6/CFML_Reference/functions-pt170.htm#1103962